# How to Set SSIS Encryption Level Protection within Visual Studios 2013

Tags: ssis

i have SSIS package that runs on visual studio 2013. Since lots of people will be using this package i want to set the protection level to server level when i deploy the package to our server. However, i do not  see this option on VS 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try to accomplish your goal that way:

1. Open package in VS editor.
2. Click on any empty space inside the package.
3. Go to File - "Save Copy of YourPackageName As..." - beware: this option not always visible, but should be visible when you do previous item (2).
4. Choose SQL Server, YourServerName, Path, etc, and then select Protection level: "Rely on server storage and roles for access control".

I think it's that you want.
Hope this helps.